# bootstrap modal box open jquery location picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I work With jquery location picker plugin for google map. now, I open map into bootstrap 3.0 modal box. This worked, But I need to:  when click in save changes button show longitude and latitude in result input box.

JS:

```
$('#us2').locationpicker({
    location: {
        latitude: 46.15242437752303,
        longitude: 2.7470703125
    },
    radius: 300,
    inputBinding: {
        latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
        longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
        radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
        locationNameInput: $('#us2-address')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnModal").click(function () {
        //How Can I Copy myDiv here so that I can also view it in Modal
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $("#myDiv").appendTo(".modal-body");
    });

    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#myDiv").prependTo("body");

    })
});
```

HTML :

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Location:
                <input type="text" id="us2-address" style="width: 200px" />Radius:
                <input type="text" id="us2-radius" />
                <div id="us2" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>Lat.:
                <input type="text" id="us2-lat" />Long.:
                <input type="text" id="us2-lon" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
result lat: <input type="text" id="lat" />
result long: <input type="text" id="lon" />
```

I have result long and result lat for input/join value form modal box when click in save changes button. How to create This ?

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/hagR2/

Comment: There is no `#myDiv` in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the "save changes" `btn` an id :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-changes">Save changes</a>
```

add a click handler to the `btn` that transfers the values to the main page and closes the modal :

```
$("#save-changes").click(function() {
   $("#lat").val($('#us2-lat').val());
   $("#lon").val($('#us2-lon').val());        
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv7w/**

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/hagR2/2/

**JS:-**

```
$('#us2').locationpicker({
    location: {
        latitude: 46.15242437752303,
        longitude: 2.7470703125
    },
    radius: 300,
    inputBinding: {
        latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
        longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
        radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
        locationNameInput: $('#us2-address')
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnModal").click(function () {
        //How Can I Copy myDiv here so that I can also view it in Modal
        $("#myModal").modal('show');

        $("#myDiv").appendTo(".modal-body");
    });

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#lat").val($("#us2-lat").val());
        $("#lon").val($("#us2-lon").val());

    })
});
```